# How can I tell excel to paste new data to the next empty row?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using advance filter and macro on excel to copy "active" status rows in another workbook. How can I tell excel to paste new data to the next empty row? Here is my macro code:

```vb
CriteriaRange:=Range("Z1:Z2"), CopyToRange:=Range("A1:V1"), Unique:=False
```

resolution to paste new data to the next empty row

Comment: Where is `the next empty row`, activeworkbook  or other? What's `another workbook`?

Comment: Please share the complete (relevant) code and screenshots of your worksheets.